# Byte array always return decimal not integer in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, client-server, calculator

I try to create a simple calculator with client-server diagram in c# using System.Net.Socket. Everything working, but in server side, when I try to convert values receive from client, it's always convert the values to decimal, not integer but I try many time, still not solve.

Example, when client input a=5 and b=5 value, in a server side it's turn to 53 and 53.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Server_Fix
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int SendVarData(Socket s, byte[] data)
        {
            int total = 0;
            int size = data.Length;
            int dataleft = size;
            int sent;

            byte[] datasize = new byte[4];
            datasize = BitConverter.GetBytes(size);
            sent = s.Send(datasize);

            while (total < size)
            {
                sent = s.Send(data, total, dataleft, SocketFlags.None);
                total += sent;
                dataleft -= sent;
            }
            return total;
        }

        private static byte[] ReceiveVarData(Socket s)
        {
            int total = 0;
            int recv;
            byte[] datasize = new byte[4];

            recv = s.Receive(datasize, 0, 4, 0);
            int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(datasize,0);
            int dataleft = size;
            byte[] data = new byte[size];


            while (total < size)
            {
                recv = s.Receive(data, total, dataleft, 0);
                if (recv == 0)
                {
                    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("exit ");
                    break;
                }
                total += recv;
                dataleft -= recv;
            }
            return data;
        }


        public static void Main()
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            byte[] data1 = new byte[1024];
            byte[] data2 = new byte[1024];
            byte[] data3 = new byte[1024];
            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 9050);

            Socket newsock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            newsock.Bind(ipep);
            newsock.Listen(10);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client...");

            Socket client = newsock.Accept();
            IPEndPoint newclient = (IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
            Console.WriteLine("Connected with {0} at port {1}",
                            newclient.Address, newclient.Port);

            string welcome = "CALCULATOR CLIENT-SERVER DIAGRAM!";
            data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
            int sent = SendVarData(client, data);

            string phepToan;
            int result=0;
            int a = 0, b = 0;
            while(true)
            {


                sent = SendVarData(client, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Nhap vao so a: "));
                data1 = ReceiveVarData(client); 

                //Console.WriteLine("Client: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
                sent = SendVarData(client, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Nhap vao so b: "));
                data2 = ReceiveVarData(client); 
                //b = Convert.ToInt32(data2);
                sent = SendVarData(client, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Cho biet phep tinh can dung la | + | - | * | / |: "));
                data3 = ReceiveVarData(client); 
                phepToan = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data3);
                //a = Convert.ToString(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data1));
                if (phepToan=="+")
                {
                    foreach (byte byteValue in data1)
                    {
                        a = Convert.ToChar(byteValue);  //It's always turn to Decimal values                                             
                    }
                    foreach (byte byteValue in data2)
                    {
                        b = Convert.ToChar(byteValue); //It's always turn to Decimal values
                    }
                    result = a + b; 

                    sent = SendVarData(client, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Ket qua phep tinh: "+Convert.ToString(result)));
                }
                if (phepToan == "-")
                {

                }
                if (phepToan == "*")
                {

                }
                if (phepToan == "/")
                {

                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from {0}", newclient.Address);
            client.Close();
            newsock.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

================================================================
Code of client side

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Client_Fix
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int SendVarData(Socket s, byte[] data)
        {
            int total = 0;
            int size = data.Length;
            int dataleft = size;
            int sent;

            byte[] datasize = new byte[4];
            datasize = BitConverter.GetBytes(size);
            sent = s.Send(datasize);

            while (total < size)
            {
                sent = s.Send(data, total, dataleft, SocketFlags.None);
                total += sent;
                dataleft -= sent;
            }
            return total;
        }

        private static byte[] ReceiveVarData(Socket s)
        {
            int total = 0;
            int recv;
            byte[] datasize = new byte[4];

            recv = s.Receive(datasize, 0, 4, 0);
            int size = BitConverter.ToInt32(datasize,0);
            int dataleft = size;
            byte[] data = new byte[size];

            while (total < size)
            {
                recv = s.Receive(data, total, dataleft, 0);
                if (recv == 0)
                {
                    data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("exit ");
                    break;
                }
                total += recv;
                dataleft -= recv;
            }
            return data;
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int sent;
            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 9050);

            Socket server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                server.Connect(ipep);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to server.");
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                return;
            }
            string input;
            data = ReceiveVarData(server);
            string stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
            Console.WriteLine(stringData);
            while (true)
            {

                data = ReceiveVarData(server);            
                Console.Write("Server: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));

                Console.WriteLine("You: " + input);
                sent = SendVarData(server, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input));

                data = ReceiveVarData(server);
                Console.Write("Server: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));

                input = Console.ReadLine();
                //Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
                Console.WriteLine("You: " + input);
                sent = SendVarData(server, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input));


                data = ReceiveVarData(server);
                Console.Write("Server: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));

                input = Console.ReadLine();
                //Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
                Console.WriteLine("You: " + input);
                sent = SendVarData(server, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input));

                data = ReceiveVarData(server);
                Console.WriteLine("Server: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Disconnecting from server...");
            server.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            server.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mcve], show the client code and the bytes that are transmitted over the network. Also, please bear in mind that "decimal not integer" doesn't really make sense with the code you've given. Your code never uses the `decimal` type, so it's really unclear what you mean.

Comment: 53 is the Unicode codepoint (formerly ASCII) for the character '5'.
You are doing one step of decoding too much somewhere.

Comment: Ya... I know but I still find out what step doing this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume `byteValue` is 53, the codepoint of the character '5'.

Then

```
Convert.ToChar(byteValue)
```

will give 53. That's fine, chars in C# have a numeric value, which is their ordinal in the character table.

One way to solve your problem would be this:

```
var a = int.Parse(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { bytevalue }));
```

Or, again with some speculation, more likely:

```
var a = int.Parse(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data1));
```

Here, the numeric representation of the character digit '5' as it comes over the wire (as 53), will be looked up in the ASCII table, giving "5", and then parsed into the desired integer.

But it does not fix the root problems with the whole code, which would require a more thorough planning of how bits of information are to be encoded, transported, and subsequently decoded in a reliable fashion.

Comment: Thank you @dlatikay very much!